# making variables completely invisible to user until he does a specific thing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have 3 main code classes:
1) node.js (running express)
2) the index.html (which loads the moment we enter the site)
3) sck.js which does something (I will explain it after the first and second files)

what I basically do is, I want the user to click on a button. and then the server will output on the page (HTML) or, alert (does not matter to me)
a specific line/word...

I am going literally crazy, I've searched everywhere...

I don't want the user to see the secret word until he clicks the button. not even in the source code (F12) !!!

sck.js is just a jquery that listens to a button click.

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

//Set a static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log(`starting server port 3000`);
} );
```

in index.html there is just a button, waiting for the user to click it.

TL;DR : **how do I make a variable COMPLETELY invisible for the user, until he clicks a button?**

I thought about saving the secret in app.js (because the user cant see whats written there...) and then passing it somehow to the html... but I cant!!!

doesn't it suppose to be easy? it sounds like that .... :(

Thanks!!

Comment: It's not possible to have the number on the client side and make it invisible. What you should do, is keep the variable on the node side of things, then make a request to the server to get that variable once the user clicks the button.

Comment: You have to add code to your express so it can send the word to your page after loading it, usually through an ajax call. It's impossible to hide things inside code you'll send to the browser. You could obfuscate or hide the word alot, but in the end only getting the word from the server will be guaranteed that the user can't know in advance.

Comment: @Xizam so basically creating a new file with all the info and then querying it from there? how do I do such a thing? thanks!

Comment: Add a route to your express that will return one word from a file on the node server or something. Plenty of tutorials out there for basic express routes.

Comment: how about the button call api for secret code ?

Comment: @Shilly I'll be more clear just not to confuse everyone: it's basically a mini (and stupid) CTF, it's the first challenge... so the user needs to click a button and the flag appears. now, of course I dont want him to see the flag (even if the mission is easy but lets leave it for now..) i just want to send the flag when he clicks and make it invisible otherwise

Answer (score 1):

A super simple way. Add a route to your express app:

```
app.get('/getflag', function (req, res) {
  res.send('theflag');
});
```

Add a link to your HTML

```
<a href="/getflag">Get Flag</a>
```

Click the link, you will be taken to a page with 'theflag' displayed.

Comment: but when I add the a tag (with href) then the user will be able to see that "hmm there is a /getflag" then he will just go there without doing the mission... no?   and thanks man btw!

Comment: Well yeah, everything on the client-side can be assumed to be always visible. To make it invisible, you have to remove it completely. There is no way you could connect the client to the server, if the client is not even allowed to know how to connect to the server. What you're asking is effectively impossible.

Comment: i dont know if what im asking for is impossible, but you have to agree that in a CTF, there is a challenge and you need to solve it in order to get the flag... and you cant see it otherwise... im asking how I can do the same in here using express (the user will have interface and everything) but i want him to click on a button (in the UI) and then only the flag appears

Comment: Can't you like, have the user send the solution of the challenge  to the server? Then they would still need to solve the challenge to get around your UI and load the route directly. So only the correct solution would get an answer for the flag from the express server. So explain the challenge to us.

Comment: @Shilly its the simplest game i could think of... (ive made the problem 'nicer' because the ctf is not just clicking a button and thats it...   it has to do with jquery and you need to click on a lot of buttons in 5 seconds and if you click on more than 30 then you get the secret) 
its really the simplest thing i could have thought to ask (because I am new) and it seems logical for me: user does something -> server recognizes -> server sends data to user 

no? and thanks for you guys.. i really appreciate

Comment: i just need the user to see the message after he clicks a button (to make the problem 'nicer') i dont need to validate if the flag / his input is right.. there is no input . only need to show the flag in the html or alert it in jquery/js

Comment: Nothing you've described can be done completely invisibly. At best, and with a lot of time and effort you could implement a simple anti-cheat system on your server. Remember, all of your games source code is on the client side. By that logic, the user can see how everything inside it works. Triple A games and huge software with development budgets in the millions, are cracked within days of release, because people have access to the inner workings of the software.

Comment: @JamesHay my friend told me something about 'raw socket' is it a solution? maybe it gives us a clue ? or it doesnt work.. ?

Comment: The user could still fake a socket with software and then do the same as with a normal express route. You'll have to decide between either making the anti cheating very complicated or having the  possibility that people who can code can crack it. Could you change the game in some way? For example:

Comment: If the challenge would be to press X buttons in the correct order, you could add a letter or number to each button and concat it to a string. Only the correct order of buttons wins. That way the user would still have to loop over all the possible combinations if they want to bruteforce the answer. The issue is that clicking 30 buttons randomly is something we cannot turn into a requirement that is not easy to figure out.